# How to count frequency of list of words in multiple txt files python

Tags: python, regex, path, counter

I have 450 keywords in a csv file. I would like to count frequency of occurrences of these keywords in multiple txt files in seperate folders.

Sample of csv file:

- Keyword1
- Keyword2

Expected output:

**Company names, Keyword1, Keyword2**

XYZ company, 4, 5

I am currently counting frequency of each keyword by writing code for each of them. I am looking for a solution to read csv file of keywords and count frequency of occurrences of these keywords in multiple text files.

My code:

```py
path = ['foldername1', 'foldername2']
for i in tqdm(path):
    for filename in os.listdir(i):
      with open(os.path.join(i, filename), encoding='ISO-8859-1') as filedata:
      text=filedata.read()
      keyword1=sum(1 for match in re.finditer(r"\bkeyword1", text, re.IGNORECASE))
      keyword2=sum(1 for match in re.finditer(r"\bkeyword2", text, re.IGNORECASE))
      res=re.findall("data_(\d+)_", filedata.name)
      k=' '.join(res)
      file_list.append({'company name': k,'keyword1':, 'keyword2':keyword2})
      dft=pd.DataFrame(file_list)
      dft.to_csv('keyword_count.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic method that can easily manipulated to do what you want:

```
with open('.\\keywords.csv','r') as r:
    keywords = r.read().splitlines()

with open('.\\foldername1\\file1.txt','r') as r:
    words1 = [1 for w in r.read().split() if w.lower() in keywords]

with open('.\\foldername2\\file2.txt','r') as r:
    words2 = [1 for w in r.read().split() if w.lower() in keywords]

print('Occurences of keywords in file1: {len(words1)}')
print('Occurences of keywords in file1: {len(words2)}')
```